# On the conditional expectation formula $E[X] = E \big[ E[X|Y] \big]$ vs. $E[X] = E \big[ E[X|Y=y] \big]$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I am comfortable with the fact that for two random variables $X,Y$,

$$E[X] = E \big[ E[X|Y] \big]$$

However, in my textbook, they express this as 
$$E[X] =  E \big[ E[X|Y=y] \big]$$

To me, the second expression seems incorrect since $y$ is fixed. 
As a discrete counter example, If I flip a  fair 3 sided die, let $X$ be the number that shows up on the die, and $Y$ be a binary random variable that takes 1 if $X$ is odd and $0$ otherwise.

Then clearly, $E[X] \neq E\big[ E[X|Y=0]\big]$

Am I just misunderstanding notation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is nothing  new. That is simply another notation for the same thing with the same meaning as  the case that you understand. Ignore that as a notational variation.

Comment: You are right, the identity $$E[X] =  E \big[ E[X|Y] \big]$$ is correct and the formula $$E[X] =  E \big[ E[X|Y=y] \big]$$ is absurd, and to begin with, because the RHS depends on $y$ while the LHS does not. Note that $$E \big[ E[X|Y=y] \big]=E[X|Y=y]$$ since $E[X|Y=y]$ is a number.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Sorry but your comment is **most misleading**.

Comment: You are right. $f(y) = E[X\mid Y = y]$ and $E[X\mid Y]$ is related in such a way that $f(Y) = E[X \mid Y]$. So they not only differ but also live on a priori different spaces. It make not much sense to take expectation $E$ to $f$. A possible correction to the proposed identity would be $$ E[X] = \int E[X \mid Y = y] \, F_Y(dy), $$ where $F_Y$ is the CDF of $Y$ (assuming $Y$ takes real values).

Comment: It is like using the notation $f(x)$ for a function, it should be $f$ to be precise.  But people don't get confused by this.

Comment: The notation is $EX=E[E[X|Y=y]|_{y=Y}]$ (that's the one I learned)